# How to sort only top menu by category custom attribute in magento?

Tags: magento, navigation

I have 15 categories created. and in left navigation i need categories in default order.

But in top menu I need to display categories in specific sort order. For that I have created attribute and followed this [link](http://www.netismine.com/magento/sort-categories-in-header-menu).

So from above link, sorting is done by name, but i need to sort by int value stored in custom attribute

So please help anybody!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function you mentioned with a small alteration: instead of getName() use getYourAttribute().

That is, however, not all. The nodes of the menu tree do not have your attribute in their internal data storage yet. To add it there, you'll have to create a class that overrides the catalog observer model, specifically the function Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::_addCategoriesToMenu. this function is responsible for populating the top menu with category nodes.

Make sure that your overridden function adds your attribute in this procedure:

```
$categoryData = array(
     'name' => $category->getName(),
     'id' => $nodeId,
     'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
     'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
     'your_attribute' => $category->getYourAttribute()
);
```

I feel uneasy about modifying the **lib** files with custom code, as the tutorial suggests, but if this is your last resort...

Comment: Thanks for reply. But Sorting using custom attribute how can i implement and where I need to change? and I have undone lib data changes and implements as your suggestion. So please help!!